# Configure Node Access in Rules

Tags: rules

I have a content management site where users can pay to view a node for a certain content type. To make it happen, I am thinking to leverage rules: when the user purchases a node to read, his access to this node is granted by the rule.

I have been searching around for a few days but didn't make much progress. I installed module ACL, but unable to configure it in rules; I also have Node Access Control, but also was unable to move forward with it. Currently, I have UC installed as my eCommerce platform and I am on Drupal 7.

Need advice from experts like you.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Sure you can do this with Rules. Before posting an answer (including an appropriate rule), what would be the Rules Event you want such rule to be triggered, i.e. relate to your "*when the user purchases a node to read*"?